# Extract Integer part value which is only ID in given file

Tags: java

I have written a program to extract all integer value in the file and find the duplicate integer. But I want only those Integer value which is like `ID="****.." / id="****.."`. I don't want to consider `"dependsOnPresenceOf"` value whatever it is.

My File is : for example

```
  <line id="24867948" dependsOnPresenceOf="7417840">
            <element text="Card Balance " id="18829409" dependsOnPresenceOf="28696224" />
  <line id="2597826922" dependsOnPresenceOf="200114712343">
            <methodElement fixedWidth="17" precededBySpace="false" id="418710522">
  <line id="24867948" dependsOnPresenceOf="10565536">
            <element text="  Cert. Number:" id="23917950" dependsOnPresenceOf="10565536" />
  <line id="24867948" dependsOnPresenceOf="10565536">
        <element text="  Cert. Number:" id="23917950" dependsOnPresenceOf="10565536" />
```

My Program is below which i have written to extract Integer value only :

```
public class DuplicateIDPicker {

protected static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(com.aspire.pos.DuplicateIDPicker.class);

public static String finalContent = "";

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String content = "";
    /* Set location of the file as format below */
    String path = "D://TASK/DuplicateFinder/OriginalFile/";
    /* Set file name to be evaluate with extension */
    String fileName = "SSLItems.bpt";

    File f = new File(path.concat(fileName));

    try {
        content = readFile(f);
        String extractedInteger = content.replaceAll("\\D+", " ");
        String[] arrayOfID = findAllIDInArray(extractedInteger);

        System.out.println("***********************");

        HashSet<String> set    = new HashSet<String>();
        HashSet<String> newSet = new HashSet<String>();
        System.out.println("Duplicate ID's found :");
        for (String arrayElement : arrayOfID) {
            if (!set.add(arrayElement)) {
                // System.out.println("Duplicate Element is : "+arrayElement);
                newSet.add(arrayElement);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        /* here are all Duplicate Id */
        System.out.println(newSet);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static String readFile(File f) throws IOException {
    String data = "";

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Print the content on the console
        finalContent = finalContent + data;
    }

    return finalContent;
}

public static String[] findAllIDInArray(String str) {
    String[] value = str.split(" ");
    return value;
}
}
```

Comment: If the file format is XML, you can use XML parsers to extract the data.

Comment: You can ensure xml attribute uniquenesness with xml schema. It has right functionality to do this. But you will need to read and practice quite a bit. And do not read xml directly, there is APIs for that. Using these you can validate xml with schemas.

Comment: but this is not an xml file right ?

Comment: looks like one to me... what is bpt extension?

Comment: CorelDraw Bitmap fills related to print. always things are dissimilar. haha

Comment: be aware that in readFile() method you do not close the readers. that might be potential reasource link and in any case is bad practice.  Java 7 has a one-line read entire file into String way (google it)

Comment: ok, but if it is a text file that has hierarchical <elements> it can be read and parsed as xml

Comment: Hou put @SuppressWarnings("resource"), but you evidently do not know what that means and when it is right to use it.

Comment: See Yes you may correct. But that story was told by eclipse thats why I have done this for a reason with resource concern

Comment: Looks like XML to me. Have you tried using XML tools?

Answer (score 1):

you can do `content.replaceAll("dependsOnPresenceOf=\"\\d+\"", "");` to remove these unwanted strings

Comment: would it remove with associated Integer value to this field "dependsOnPresenceOf" ? Ok let me check . Thanks in advance !!

Comment: any news?? did you check??

Comment: But finally I have written another program to fight with this problem.

Comment: Do you want me to share my solution but. This one is optimized or not ?

Can you please check and tell me the mistake which  I have done in writing another code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution that makes use of:

1) Java 7 read entire file in one line
2) Matcher ability to sequentially find occurences that match the expression
3) regex capturing group to get the desired numeric value

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DuplicateIDPicker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /* Set location of the file as format below */
        String path = "C://Temp/";
        /* Set file name to be evaluate with extension */
        String fileName = "in.txt";

        Set<String> all = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<>();

        String regex = "(id|ID)\\=\"" // attribute name + quoted equal and quotation
                + "(\\d+)"  // id value marked as (capturing group)
                + "\"";     // closing quotation
        try {
            String content = readFile(path + fileName);
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(content);
            while (m.find()) {
                String idValue = m.group(2);
                if (!all.add(idValue)) duplicates.add(idValue);
            }
            System.out.println(duplicates);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String readFile(String fileFullPath) throws IOException
    {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileFullPath)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working correctly. And thank you for sharing this advanced technique to handle such king of scenario.

To read about how regex is work, share me any link if possible. Thanks @sharonbn

Answer (score 0):

```
  This one is another solution to solve my problem.

    public class DuplicateIDPicker {
    protected static final Logger logger = Logger
                .getLogger(com.aspire.pos.DuplicateIDPickerOld.class);

    public static String finalContent = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
                IOException {

        String content = "";
        String[] arrayOFId = {};
        String[] listOfID = {};
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        HashSet<String> newSet = new HashSet<String>();

        /* Set location of the file as format below */
        String path = "D://TASK/DuplicateFinder/OriginalFile/";
        /* Set file name to be evaluate with extension */
        String fileName = "SSLPickupDeliveryOrderReceipt.txt";

        File f = new File(path.concat(fileName));

        content = readFile(f);
        arrayOFId = findAllIDInString(content);
        listOfID = extractIDOnly(arrayOFId);

        System.out.println("***********************");

        System.out.println("Duplicate ID's found :");
        for (String arrayElement : listOfID) {
            if (!set.add(arrayElement)) {
                newSet.add(arrayElement);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        /* Duplicate Id stored in a Set : */
        System.out.println(newSet);

    }

    /*
     * This method is implemented to read file and 
     * return content in String format
     */
    public static String readFile(File f) {
        String data = "";
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                finalContent = finalContent + data;
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return finalContent;
    }


    /*
     * This method is implemented to get Array string 
     * on the basis of '"'
     */
    public static String[] extractIDOnly(String[] arr) {
        ArrayList<String> listOfID = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            String newString = arr[i];
            String[] finalString = {};
            for (int j = 0; j < newString.length();) {
                finalString = newString.split("\"", 3);
                for (int k = 1; k < finalString.length;) {
                    listOfID.add(finalString[1]);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }

        }
        return (String[]) listOfID.toArray(new String[listOfID.size()]);
    }

    /*
     * This method is implemented to split the ID part only
     */
    public static String[] findAllIDInString(String str) {
        String[] value = str.split("id=");
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unclear as to whether this is _the answer to your question_ or another unsuccessful attempt. If the latter, it should be an edit to the question.

Comment: I solved it by my own today with different logic. This is an alternative for me only. If you want to delete this then Its Ok, do it sir.
Its exact solution what I wanted. I don't know that it will solve your problem in the future or not but definitely it will help somewhere or someone